# Writing your first Django app, part 3, polls questions do not show in the browser

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse

I am following [DJango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/).

```
 return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

does not return polls question and I get the message that 'No polls are available.'

I have exactly followed tutorial but I cannot get the result.

view:

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list=Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]    
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest question  list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

index.html

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            <li><a href="/polls/{{question.id}}/">{{question.question_text}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>why No polls available now</p>
{% endif %}
```

database screenshot:
[image]

model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

def __str__(self):
    return self.question_text

def was_published_recently(self):
    return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: It means, there is no `polls` in your DB

Comment: There are polls. When i run the following view, the polls are dispalyes

Comment: def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    output = ', '.join([q.question_text for q in latest_question_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)

Comment: Can you add you view and template code to the question?

Comment: `latest question  list` - Your context has spaces, it should use underscores as per your template

Comment: Thanks @Sayse, it solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid context variable name in view, it should be `latest_question_list` instead of `latest question  list` same as in the template:

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list=Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]    
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: I don't understand why some people downvote a valid and accepted answer without any explanation.